# How to create a circle objects and push them to array?

Tags: javascript, html

This is a homework problem. I need to create circles in HTML5 canvas so that with every click, there is a circle created that is random in color. The center of the circle is where the mouse was clicked. However, if the new circle crated overlaps any other circles that were already drawn, those circles disappear while new circle stays. That logic with overlapping I think I can manage. The issue I have is to how to keep track on all the circles that are drawn on canvas?

```js
(function(doc) {
  var canvas = doc.getElementById("testCanvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  // Click event handler
  canvas.onclick = function(e) {
    // Creating array for circles
    var circles = [];

    // Creating a circle with random color and a given radius at the mouse click
    var nextColor = randomColor();
    context.fillStyle = nextColor;
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(e.clientX, e.clientY, 30, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    context.fill();
    context.closePath();

    // Creating circle object
    var circle = {
      x_coord: e.clientX,
      y_coord: e.clientY,
      color: nextColor,
      visible: true
    };

    // Pushing circle object into the array of circles
    circles.push(circle);

    //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = circles;
    console.log(circles);
  };
})(document);
```

```html
<canvas id="testCanvas" />
```

Comment: The randomColor() function is defined in separate js file...

Comment: Keep all the circles in the array and intersect the new circle with the existing ones in the array.  Once they are rasterized on the canvas, all information about them is lost.

Comment: Your `var circles = [];` needs to happen outside of the click listener. If it's inside, the array will be replaced on each click (and the previous circle will be forgotten.)

Comment: Cat, you seem to be correct. When I console.log it, I see as many arrays as clicks on canvas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only real problem I saw with your code is that you are initializing the circles array *inside* the click handler. This means that your circle array will have a max length of one since it gets reinitialized on each click.

Instead, initialize the circle array once by moving the following to outside of the click handler.

```
var circles = [];
```

Example:

```js
(function (doc) {
  var canvas = doc.getElementById("testCanvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  // Creating array for circles 
  var circles = [];

  // Click event handler
  canvas.onclick = function (e) {

    // Creating a circle with random color and a given radius at the mouse click
    var nextColor = "black";
    context.fillStyle = nextColor;
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(e.clientX, e.clientY, 30, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    context.fill();
    context.closePath();

    // Creating circle object
    var circle = {
      x_coord: e.clientX, y_coord: e.clientY, color:
        nextColor, visible: true
    };

    // Pushing circle object into the array of circles
    circles.push(circle);

    console.log(circles);
  }

})(document);
```

```css
canvas {
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="testCanvas" />
```

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to solve the issue I was having!